# How much data does Google Maps navigation use?

Tags: google-maps, data-monitoring, google-maps-navigation

Does anyone have a rough number for how much data Google Maps navigation uses per, say, 100 miles or something? I know it will vary slightly by user and area, but I'm just looking for an average/estimate.

I'm going to be driving to Canada soon, and trying to estimate how much "International Data" I should purchase on my plan to cover the Google Maps Navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I did a brief test the other day... only drove about 80 miles, ... obviously longer drives would give better averaging samples.

But from my short drive, it seems that Maps navigation uses roughly 1 MB for every 10 miles.

Comment: also note that Maps will cache the map data; so as long as the map can fit into the allocated cache space, it should use less data if you drive along the same roads. You might also want to precache the map while on a Wifi and use offline navigation if you have a recent enough navigation.

Comment: Precaching really wasn't possible, because I needed to cache the basically the whole state of New York and some of Canada, and it was too large an area. Would be nice if from the Google Maps website you could select a route, and ask it to cache everything 20 miles off that route to your device. Ultimately wound up using [Sygic GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sygic.aura&hl=en). It allows you to download regions as offline maps. Worked very well, even in some pretty rural, backwoods areas of Canada.